# How accurate is using millimeters in CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to use `mm` in CSS as opposed to the standard `px`.

first is this even possible?

if so, can i use it like this:

```
#div{
width:200mm;
height:100mm;
}
```

I did try to convert the millimeters to pixels so I can use the pixels value but every converter returns a different value which is strange. even Photoshop converts it and gives me a different value.

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: Why `mm`...are you planning on printing something?

Comment: @Paulie_D, Yes, exactly.

Comment: To what level of discrepancy are you seeing? For the most part, the measurements should be the same but there may be an issue in the different levels of precision of the software.

Comment: Then what the px value is doesn't matter. Just use `mm` and they should print out at that size. So, use `px` in your screen stylesheet and use `mm` in your print stylesheet. Not sure what problem you are trying to solve,

Comment: @Paulie_D, sorry mate. a bit confused! what is the print stylesheet? do I need to have two different stylesheets ? and if so, when would the second one come into action? I mean at what stage?

Comment: The print stylesheet is only used when printing...sizing everything on screen in `mm` would be unusual....and non-responsive. Try searching for "print stylsheets" or "print media queries".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [CSS Values and Units Module Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/) defines the [`mm` unit](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths) as 1/10th of 1cm. It also defines the `cm` unit as 96px/2.54.

In CSS, 200mm and 100mm are always equal to the same `px` value:

For 200mm:

```
cm = (200mm / 10)
px = cm * (96 / 2.54)

-> 755.91px
```

For 100mm:

```
cm = (100mm / 10)
px = cm * (96 / 2.54)

-> 377.95px
```

(Note that these values are rounded).

Comment: ok, and how would I use this calculation? is this an actual CSS calculation?

Comment: It's a calculation based on the CSS Values and Units Module Level 3, which tells browsers how to implement different units (like `mm` and `px`). 1 CSS millimetre is equal to 1/10 * 96 / 2.54 CSS pixels.

Comment: So basically, If I use this calculation and then use the given dimensions to create whatever I want (an image for example) and send it off for printing and the dimensions would be exactly correct in mm?

Comment: @rooz in theory, yes.

Comment: i don't know why it frightens me when people say ' in theory' :D... that to me sounds like (maybe yes, maybe not) and it seems like there is not a definite answer! am I correct thinking that?

Comment: @rooz well I think that'd come down to certain external aspects; the browser, perhaps; the printer drivers; the printer itself. I certainly can't guarantee that 1mm² in CSS will equate to exactly 1mm² when printed, but in theory it should.

Comment: @rooz in CSS get used to "most likely to..." since a large amount of properties and behaviour depends on a large amount of factors, so you try to get the most accurate result

Comment: So how would all of these printing companies have some sort of web application for custom products and then they get the exact size at the end from what the users designed from their browsers onto the print?